# Im trying to add an onClick function on the button so if the user clicks Yes, it removes the two buttons then add two new inputs field react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, event-handling, jsx

> this is the first code with the buttons elements

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./button.css";

function Button1() {
  return (
    <div className="buttons">
      <button>yes</button>
      <button>No</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Button1;
```

> while this is where the button component is called and rendered, i think this
> is where the logic will happen

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Button1 from "./button/Button1";
import Button2 from "./button/Button2";
import Button3 from "./button/Button3";
import CardContent from "./CardContent";


function RightBody() {
  return (
    <Card>
      <SmallCircle />
      <Div>
        <CardContent number={"1."} title={"Course of study in school:"} />
        <CardContent number={"2."} title={"Are you a student?"} />
        <Button1 />
        <Sec1>
          <CardContent number={"3."} title={"Did you graduate?"} />
          <Button2 />
        </Sec1>
        <Sec2>
          <CardContent number={"4."} title={"Did you graduate?"} />
          <Button3 />
        </Sec2>
      </Div>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

export default RightBody;

> again what I want to do is that onClick of the yes button, I want to display two input fields instead of the two  buttons originally there. Theres going to be a little icon by the side of the newly created input fields which when clicked takes the user back to the first case which is the two Yes and No buttons

```
const Div = styled.div`
  margin-top: -6%;
`;
const Card = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  width: 659px;
  height: 684px;
  left: 650px;
  top: 220px;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 29px #f0f3ff;
  border-radius: 35px;
  &:hover {
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }
`;
const SmallCircle = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  left: 92%;
  top: 3%;
  border-radius: 0px;

  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #800165 0%, #d3014e 100%);
  border-radius: 50px;
  &:hover {
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }
`;
const Sec1 = styled.div`
  margin-top: -11%;
`;
const Sec2 = styled.div`
  margin-top: -12%;
`;
```

> This is my styles for the RightBody component
> [this is how it should be befor the click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUhv1.png)

[then after the click this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2DGC.png)

Comment: You have to use state

Comment: I know im to use state i dont just know the logic @KonradLinkowski, please can you help me out with the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to solving this problem is to remember if the button was clicked as yet using `React.useState()`.

Then, use the ternary operator `<condition> ? <value if true> : <value if false>` to conditionally control what elements need to be rendered.

```
function Button1({onClickYes}) {
  return (
    <div className="buttons">
      <button onClick={onClickYes}>yes</button>
      <button>No</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const DEFAULT_IS_CLICKED = false;
function RightBody() {
  const [isClickedYes, setIsClickedYes] = React.useState(DEFAULT_IS_CLICKED)

  const onClickYes = () => {
    setIsClickedYes(true)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {isClickedYes 
         ? <>
             <input/>
             <input/>
           </>
         : <Button1 onClickYes={onClickYes} />
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Notice how I used a React Fragment `<>...</>` to wrap your two input boxes. These act like parentheses since you can only return one element at a time (with as many child nodes as you want)